# Can't determine the user's config path

Tags: svn

I'm using the svn library as part of my web application to rerteive text files. I'm getting the following error:

> Can't determine the user's config path

The weird thing is that I can access other command line tools and checkout my files without any problem.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Perhaps http://www.svnforum.org/threads/31131-svn-Can%E2%80%99t-determine-the-user%E2%80%99s-config-path is related?

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but for me it was the AppPool identity user. I changed it to localsystem and it worked. The AppPool user should have the proper permissions to access the file.